# What is the proper way to override the getFinalPrice method based on value of 2 customizable option text fields?

Tags: magento2, product, price, custom-options

I want to change the final value on `getFinalPrice` in `Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\Price` so that I can modify the price based on the value of 2 customizable option text fields. I am using "$product->getCustomOption('option_' . $option->getId())" to get the value of my options on the page.

Here are my conditions with additional amounts:

1. Field1: "Corn"

   Field2: "2 Rows"

   +$2 (add 2 dollars)
2. Field1: "Corn"

   Field2: "3 Rows"

   +$3 (add 3 dollars)
3. Field1: "Pesticide"

   Field2: "Airplane"

   +basePrice * 0.05 (add 5% of the basePrice)

Below is the picture of my test product with 2 text fields representing my 2 test fields (Field1 and Field2)

I feel like Magento 2 probably has an easy way to override this Price using plugins. I may make multiple copies of this plugin class so that I can also change by percentage and also be able to turn on/off customizations easily. Observers may not be ideal in this case because I need to take into account the order that I process these custom attribute prices.

[image: Price Dependent on 2 Text Fields]

What I have so far...

```
<?php

namespace Cpf\PriceAdjustment\Plugin\Product\Type;

class PricePlugin{
    public function __construct(
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
        , \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository){
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    }
    public function aroundGetFinalPrice(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\Price $subject, callable $proceed, $qty, \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product){
        $this->logger->debug("test");
        $result = $proceed($qty, $product);

        $this->logger->debug(print_r($result, true));
        $finalPrice = $result;
        // $finalPrice = 2015.00;
        // $product->setFinalPrice($finalPrice);
        $id = $product->getSku();
        $this->logger->debug(print_r($id, true));
        $option_ids = $product->getCustomOption('option_ids');
        if($option_ids){
            $this->logger->debug(print_r("I got some options now..." . rand(), true));
            //$this->logger->debug(print_r($option_ids, true));
            foreach (explode(',', $option_ids->getValue()) as $optionId) {
                $this->logger->debug(print_r($optionId, true));
                if ($option = $product->getOptionById($optionId)) {
                    $confItemOption = $product->getCustomOption('option_' . $option->getId());


                    $this->logger->debug(print_r($confItemOption->getValue(), true));

                    $group = $option->groupFactory($option->getType())
                        ->setOption($option)
                        ->setConfigurationItemOption($confItemOption);
                    //$finalPrice += $group->getOptionPrice($confItemOption->getValue(), $basePrice);
                }
            }
        }
        return $finalPrice;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> What is the proper way to [...] adjust the final price base on 2 customizable option text field value?

Use the  `catalog_product_get_final_price` event that is fired in `getFinalPrice()`.

The `product` parameter is a product instance that also contains the selected custom options. You should find your custom values in `$product->getCustomOptions()`

Comment: Thank you! Is this the documentation on observers that I should follow? http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/extension-dev-guide/events-and-observers.html I'm assuming that if I use the observer, it will show the new price in cart and checkout as well? I will try it out.

Comment: @Amad Yes and yes. Did it work?

Comment: Yes it did. I was able to change the price. However, many google searches later, I am finding myself wanting to use plugins. Many have suggested plugins are better to future proof any customizations. The observers will work, but it does not take into account the order that observers will execute (at least not very easily). I can imagine future cases where the order (that I will process custom option price changes) will affect the price (namely percentage based pricing schemes). Thank you, though, this got me thinking on other things that cannot be overridden using plugins.

Comment: This has help because I was able to find Magento 1 code that looked similar to what I was doing while searching for price observers. I converted it for my Magento 2 plugin class. Hopefully, soon I will have an answer that takes care of all the cases.